# assigning GET response to the scope variable

Tags: angularjs, ajax, rest

I have developed my application on simulated data like below .

```
$scope.products=[{serial:1,quantity:30,name:"aaa"},
                 {serial:2,quantity:10,name:"bbb"}];
```

also i have prepared the rest resource which fetched data from database and available at http://localhost:8080/myrests/shop/productresource

can you please help me how can i assign this resource return results to the above `$scope.products`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it asynchronously use promis 
    //below code wrap inside a function

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get(URL) 
.then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
    console.log("Success " + data);
},
function(data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.reject(data);
    console.log("Failure " + status);
});
return deferred.promise;
```

else simply use $http

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/myrests/shop/productresource") 
.then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.products = data;
},
function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Failure " + status);
});
```